# Using javascript to inline form label and fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, forms

I have a form where the contact form has labels and fields, but they are all on newlines. I want to use JS to make it so the labels and their respective field are on the same line, for A/B testing for Optimizely.

Assume no access to the markup (JS only).

I have a JSFiddle of my form here: http://jsfiddle.net/2thjbt9m/1/

I've tried setting the fields to `inline-block` but it doesn't seem to do the trick.

Comment: what about access to css? This doesnt need to be done with JS

Comment: what you need do that with js? Why just not use css???

Comment: Since you're using bootstrap, have a look at [Horizontal form](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-horizontal).

Comment: Those `<label>`s' `for` attributes are wrong. They should match the `id`s of their respective inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do this with JS by targeting the input class and setting the input to `inline-block`:

```
$(".input-lg").css({"display": "inline-block", "width":"60%"});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/2thjbt9m/6/)

Comment: This seems like the simplest working solution, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could override the styles with custom CSS, though that may not be the "bootstrap way" to do it.

The `input` fields being `inline-block` is needed, but not enough, because they a) have 100% width, and b) `.form-group` is only 50% width, both which contribute to them sitting on their own line.

**CSS**

```
div.form-group{
 width:100%;
}
div.form-group > input{
    width:65%;
    display:inline-block;
}
div.form-group > label{
    width:30%;
}
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2thjbt9m/3/

if **JS** is needed, you can set the styles directly with JS

```
$('div.form-group').css({width:'100%'});
$('div.form-group > input').css({width:'65%',display:'inline-block'});
$('div.form-group > label').css({width:'30%'});
```

fiddle 2: http://jsfiddle.net/2thjbt9m/4/

Comment: Is there a way to do this JS-only? That's my biggest hurdle. If I had access to the CSS/markup, this would be very easy.